# Selenium2Library keywords are not shown in RobotFrameworrk

Tags: robotframework

I installed Robot Framework and Selenium2Library.

When I start RIDE and write test case, I can only see the default RF keywords and can't see the Selenium ones.

I know I have to add them as a resource or library but don't know how exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
it is 'Selenium2Library'.you can click 'tools ' and view ride log.
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this path to your particular test suite.

../../../../Python27/Lib/site-packages/Selenium2Library/

1. Click on test suite.
2. settings >> library >> paste the above URL.

You can use then in that test suite.

Hope this will help you.

`Suppa.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add the library...

It can be done as : go to `Edit` --> Click on `Library` 
Give 'Name' as `'Selenium2Library`' and click on OK

check the library added and it should display the '`Selenium2Library`' in black color words.

If 'Yes' it is installed properly and you can use it.

click on 'K' with Search icon next (Keyword Search) option, there you can search the keywords by selecting 'source' as Selenium2Library from the drop down, which gives the documentation also.

Thanks
Sarada